# How can I solve problems with Remesh modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I used the Remesh modifier to turn an Ocean modifier blocky and this happened. What's going on?

The model shown below should just look like normal terrain, but it doesn't. There are walls covering it.

View from inside:
[image: From inside the bug]

View from outside:
[image: From outside the bug]

Comment: HI, welcome, please add some more information about what exactly you feel a "bug", and possibly relevant settings (modifiers) that you used in the process...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it's not bug, as the [Remesh Modifier page on Blender 2.79 Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) explain this problem and how to solve it :
[image]

Just add a *Solidify Modifier*, set the *Thickness* to **0.5**, and make sure the *Solidify Modifier* is processed before the *Remesh Modifier* but after the *Ocean Modifier*. The order of the modifiers should be, from top to bottom : *Ocean* / *Solidify* / *Remesh*.

[image]